# ORA-29537 and cleaning up no longer wanted jar file

Tags: java, oracle11g

```
dropjava -u uname/pass@orcl1 -v -r -f /software/dba/abc.jar
```

gives me

```
ORA-29537: class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly
```

If I can't find right .jar file anymore can I just use below statements in oracle? I don't plan to use that lost jar file anymore, just want to clean up so I can load a new one. I have Oracle 11gR2 on Linux 6.7

```
DROP JAVA SOURCE fa2_name;
```

And

```
DROP JAVA CLASS fa2_name;
```

Below sql

```
select *
from user_objects 
where object_type like '%JAVA%' 
;
```

[image]